# Maintenance plan to backup differentials hourly each to a new file name in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup

In addition to a nightly full backup, I'd like to set up an hourly differential backup maintenance plan in SQL Server 2012, where *each differential backup file should receive a different name*. It seems this isn't possible. Am I overlooking something simple?

In the GUI interface, my choices are either to append to the target differential backup file, or to overwrite it. Is there a way to append  _{YEAR}{MO}{DY}{HH} to the differential filename?

Comment: If you use maintenance plans or Ola H's scripts, it will do this for you.  You shouldn't need to manually (or via the GUI, for that matter) take differential backups.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Ola's backup solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). Brad talks about it in more details on [simple talk.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automate-and-improve-your-database-maintenance-using-ola-hallengrens-free-script/)

The solution is very simple to implement and its tested by [many organizations](https://ola.hallengren.com/organizations.html).

> ### Value  Description
>
> FULL   Full backup
>
> DIFF   Differential backup
>
> LOG        Transaction log backup